# Nativescript: Java to Typescript callback function/method

Tags: java, android, typescript, nativescript

I am currently trying to make ffmpegCmdSdk android library to work on nativescript and was able to manage to make it work based on adb logcats but without a callback. It's either the app freezes or just return "onStart":

Code:

```
declare const android, com, java, org: any;
var mFFmpeg = (com as any).yyl.ffmpeg.FFmpeg;
var mFFmpegUtils = (com as any).yyl.ffmpeg.FFmpegUtils;
var mFFmpegCallBack = (com as any).yyl.ffmpeg.FFmpegCallBack;
FFmpegUtils: any; //com.yyl.ffmpeg.FFmpegUtils
FFmpegCallBack: any; //ccom.yyl.ffmpeg.FFmpegCallBack

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _navigationService: NavigationService, private _ngZone: NgZone) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (mFFmpegUtils.hasCompatibleCPU(application.android.context) && mFFmpegUtils.isSport()) {
            console.log("Cpu compatible!");
            this.FFmpegUtils = mFFmpegUtils.getInstance();
            this.FFmpegUtils.isShowLogcat(true);
            this.FFmpegUtils.setDebugMode(true);
        } else {
            console.log("Cpu not compatible!");
        }
    }

    FFmpegOnClick() {
        var self = this;
        this.FFmpegUtils.execffmpeg("ffmpeg -version");
    }
```

}

with the code with just `this.FFmpegUtils.execffmpeg("ffmpeg -version");`
I know works fine as from log cat it returns

```
04-01 16:15:46.551 23034-23034/com.app.package I/FFMPEG: [ffmpeg, -version]
04-01 16:15:46.551 23034-23289/com.app.package I/FFMPEG: 命令开始
04-01 16:15:46.571 23034-23289/com.app.package I/FFMPEG: exit_program   pthread_exit=0
04-01 16:15:46.571 23034-23034/com.app.package I/FFMPEG: 线程出错被打断退出  
YYL_EXIT_
04-01 16:15:46.571 23034-23034/one.meyou.isbd I/FFMPEG: 任务完成 返回结果 =0
```

just as same as the Android Studio Project which tells me that everything works at this point. But when trying to add a callback e.g.

```
this.FFmpegUtils.execffmpeg("ffmpeg -version", new 
com.yyl.ffmpeg.FFmpegCallBack({
    onStart: function () {
        console.log('onStart');
    },

    onCallBackLog: function () {
        console.log('onCallBackLog');
    },

    onCallBackPrint: function () {
        console.log('onCallBackPrint');
    },

    onProgress: function () {
        console.log('onProgress');
    },

    onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('onSuccess');
    },

    onFailure: function () {
        console.log('onFailure');
    }
}));
```

It's either it outputs just onStart and the app freezes or it outputs something different.

the actual code from the Java callback function/method is this:

```
public FFmpegCallBack ffmpegCallBack = new FFmpegCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCallBackLog(String log) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCallBackPrint(String msg) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int frame_number, int milli_second) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int result) {

    }
};
```

Makes me wonder what am I missing or my translation wrong?
Android library is from here -> [FFmpegCmdSdk MainActivity.java](https://github.com/mengzhidaren/FFmpegCmdSdk/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yyl/demo/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Try the following syntax (using `extend` word) to create your callback  https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-cameraApp-poc/blob/master/app/main-page.js#L85-L90

Comment: And then create an instance with the `new` operator https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-cameraApp-poc/blob/master/app/main-page.js#L94

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Never have I though of it! It took me a week and never figured it out. Tried searching from different libs for examples and found non for reference :D